# Autopopulate 2 Combo box value from Selected Combo Box

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-formula, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-selected-items

[image]What is the best approach to update 2 combo box from a selected Combo box

SharePoint list Issue Tracker 
Home Center     -    Lookup
 
Supervisor      -    Person or Group    
Regional Manager -  Person or Group

[image]

Let me know if i explain it clearly. I attach some screen shot
When they select from Home Center. Supervisor and Regional Manager gets auto populated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Onchange property of HomeCenter combobox ,you can set a context variable like

```
    UpdateContext({homecenter_changed:true});
```

and set the value of the same variable as false in the page OnVisible property as

```
    UpdateContext({homecenter_changed:false});
```

Set the Items property of Supervisor ComboBox as

```
    If(homecenter_changed = true,Filter(Issue Tracker,Home Center =HomeCenter_combobox.Selected.Home Center).Supervisor)
```

Similarly,the Items property of Regional Manager can be set as

```
    If(homecenter_changed = true,Filter(Issue Tracker,Home Center =HomeCenter_combobox.Selected.Home Center).Regional Manager)
```

And in the OnChange property of both Supervisor and Regional Manager,update the context varaible back to false,then only the next time you change the value for Home Center,the other two values gets autopopulated properly,like

```
    UpdateContext({homecenter_changed:false});
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out with a Lookup function

```
LookUp(Centers, Title = DataCardValue10.Selected.Title, SupervisorEmail)
```